# Not Found when trying to POST on a Sinatra App

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I'm really new with Ruby and Sinatra so I don't know if this problem is client side or sever side. When trying to do a POST to the app I get a 404 not found error on the console log. The '/' , '/admin/ and '/connect' pages work just fine, only '/push' isn't found.

The Javascript:

```
$.post( '/arduino/public/push', notification,'json');
```

**config.ru**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require './stream'
run Sinatra::Application
```

**stream.rb**

```
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'

set :public_folder, Proc.new{File.join(root,"public")}
set server: 'thin'

get '/' do
    erb :index
end

get '/admin' do 
    erb :admin
end

def timestamp
    Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end

connections = []
notifications = []

get '/connect', provides: 'text/event-stream' do 
    stream :keep_open do |out|
        connections << out

        #out.callback on stream close evt.
        out.callback{
            #delete the connection
            connections.delete(out)
        }
    end
end

post '/push' do
    puts params
    #Add the timestamp to the notification
    notification = params.merge({'timestamp'=>timestamp}).to_json

    notifications.shift if notifications.length > 10
    connections.each{ |out| out << "data: #{notification}\n\n"}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you pushing to `/arduino/public/push`? Why not just `/arduino/push` (if `/arduino` is root of your sinatra app) or just `/push`?

This line:

```
set :public_folder, Proc.new{File.join(root,"public")}
```

suggests that `public` is for static files, therefore no routes will be triggered.